# MongoDB query executed too long

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aggregation-framework

Our production is getting slow and Application got paused for about 10-20 seconds.

Our environment

- Mongo Version 3.6.1
- Ram 128GB, R5d.x2 Amazon Instance

You guys can download log file here: https://gofile.io/?c=9Douwb

There are some suspicious points but i dont see why it took the query too long to process.
Could anyone have experiences about this problem?

I appreciate your help a lot

> 2019-08-23T02:49:57.860+0000 I COMMAND  [conn363101] command chatlogextension4.5ccd7631383cb22a2aa62c01 command: find { find: "5ccd7631383cb22a2aa62c01", filter: { $or: [ { from: "5d5f524d383cb2048c617ca4" }, { to: "5d5f524d383cb2048c617ca4" } ], _id: { $lt: ObjectId('5d5f5443383cb2044bc48ccf') }, $and: [ { type: { $ne: "REAL_GIFT" } }, { type: { $ne: "REAL_GIFT_STATUS" } } ] }, sort: { _id: -1 }, limit: 24, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "chatlogextension4" } planSummary: IXSCAN { from: 1 }, IXSCAN { to: 1 } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:2 nreturned:1 reslen:454 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 3 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 3 } } } protocol:op_query 18480ms

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue in the query performance. I can see it has used the index to filter the document. Unfortunately, I couldn't download the logs for review as it is blocked by my organization. I suspect, this could be due to some other reason like memory, network, load on the server etc.,

If you've already resolved the issue, please post the details of the issue and how you resolved

Comment: The op_query is too long (18 secs), i check back the query but it shouldn't take long like that :(